# What's a good JavaScript plugin color picker?

Tags: javascript, color-picker

I make a lot of web applications and from time to time I need a color picker. What's one that I can use like an API and doesn't require a lot of code to plug in? I also need it to work in all browsers.

Comment: https://github.com/tovic/color-picker is a tiny color picker plugin written in pure JavaScript. It is a hook-based plugin so you can simply create another function/class wrapper to extend your own custom features.

Comment: Created one with focus on design and usage https://simonwep.github.io/pickr :)

Comment: After seeing Simon's plugin and the his reluctance in addressing open issues, and the code size seemed a bit too large, I've made my own [color-picker](https://yaireo.github.io/color-picker/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Farbtastic](http://acko.net/dev/farbtastic) is a nice jQuery color picker

But apparently doesn't work in IE6

[Here](http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/#about) is another jQuery color picker that looks nice, not sure about it compatibility though.

Comment: Farbtastic is also only GPL and there are [ambiguities with GPL and JS.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239470/restrictions-of-gpl-on-javascript-libraries)

Comment: It not ambiguous. If you call GPL'd JavaScript from your JavaScript, and distribute it, then you must release your JavaScript under the GPL also. This is the same as for any other programming language.  So, please avoid GPL'd JavaScript libraries.

Comment: @SamWatkins - It *is* ambiguous. What if the library automatically runs on load? Since it's part of my page, is it all one work, or is each `<script>` a separate work? It's not immediately clear without consulting a lawyer if your bundled JS is infected by the GPL when they're included on the same page. I agree with the premise though, avoid GPL'd JS libraries.

Comment: I don't think using GPL'd code from a proprietary page is necessarily a GPL violation.  The page is a document, not a program.  But if you use GPL'd javascript from other javascript code, that javascript code at least should be released under the GPL, even if it's page-specific stuff.  GPL is a total bogosity in my opinion.  (I'm all for public domain or truly liberal licenses such as MIT.)

Answer (score 11):

I like [jscolor](http://jscolor.com/try.php) the most, lightweight and lots of options.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't personally implemented this, but I have heard good things about it, and it appears to be a great script:
http://johndyer.name/post/2007/09/PhotoShop-like-JavaScript-Color-Picker.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If your using prototype and script.aculo.us this one is great:

http://code.google.com/p/colorpickerjs/