# HTML color wheel control for website

Tags: asp.net, html, controls, components, color-picker

Is there an HTML color wheel that I can throw in my site that will return a value of the color when a user clicks on it?

would make one myself but don't want to "re-invent the wheel"

HILARIOUS(punny?)

Comment: Re-purposing the wheel, on the other hand, is progress: http://greenupgrader.com/3934/q-drum-human-water-transportation-made-easier/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SEE [What's a good JavaScript plugin color picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77431/whats-a-good-javascript-plugin-color-picker)