# colour picker in html

Tags: html, color-picker

I want to implement colour picker event in my html design, please try to help me for this design and try to send example

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's a good JavaScript plugin color picker?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77431/whats-a-good-javascript-plugin-color-picker)

Comment: Do not re-invent wheel and use some existing solution. If this is not just practice ...

Comment: Check out http://www.daviddurman.com/flexi-color-picker.
Doesn't use images neither flash nor 1px divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

[Color Picker - jQuery plugin](http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/)

There are lots of jQuery plugins available for color picker. you can just google and choose whats best suited for your requirement.

Comment: I am getting jquery conflict with this jquery. plz try to help me